# What is the probability that the range of a set of N randomly chosen real numbers in [0, 1] is less than the reciprocal of N?

Tags: pr.probability

(Random number with uniform distribution over [0, 1])

For clarification, in the case where N = 2, we can use geometric probability. On the coordinate plane consider points with 0<=x,y<=1. The condition is satisfied on a diagonal band of area 3/4 from the origin to (1,1). Similarly, with N = 3 the volume of the space in which the condition is satisfied is 7/27.

Comment: How did you compute 7/27, and why did your argument not generalize to arbitrary N?

Comment: What is meant by "the range of a set"? Is that just max minus min?

Answer (score 14):

The keyword is the [order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic). The distributions of the maximum and minimum values of a sample of $n$ independent uniformly distributed random variables are given respectively by the laws

$$U_{max}\sim \mbox{Beta}(n,1),\qquad U_{min}\sim \mbox{Beta}(1,n).$$

The range $U_{max}-U_{min}$ has a $\mbox{Beta}(n-1,2)$ distribution (see, e.g., Section 2.5 of [*A First Course in Order Statistics*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dVP-RTea5wcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=A+First+Course+in+Order+Statistics&hl=en&ei=1-AkTeC0IpiH4gbN8OjjCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)) so
$$\mathbb P\{U_{max}-U_{min} < a\}=\frac{1}{B(n-1,2)}\int_{0}^{a}x^{n-2}(1-x)dx=na^{n-1}-(n-1)a^n.$$

Comment: =$(n^2-n+1)n^{-n}$ which agrees with the examples given (however arrived at)

Comment: (Could I suggest writing $U_\max$ and $U_\min$ instead of $U_{max}$ and $U_{min}$?  The TeX code is U_\max and U_\min.  Using \max and \min not only prevents italicization, but also causes standard formatting conventions to be followed in some contexts.)

Comment: @Michael Hardy: I agree with your suggestion and I will try to stick to it in the future. I just don't think it is worth bumping up the question to make the edit.